# Properly combining words in a file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a file full of words and I am trying to write a script that basically makes every combination of 2 words from that list to another list.

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'fileutils'

path = 'Lst.lst'
temp_file = Tempfile.new('lst2.lst')
begin
  File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
    file.readlines(file).each do |line|
         file.each_line do |baseline|
                temp_file.puts line.gsub("\n", '') + baseline
        end
    end
 end
  temp_file.close
  FileUtils.mv(temp_file.path, 'lst2.lst')
ensure
  temp_file.close
  temp_file.unlink
end
```

The script runs but the outer loop only runs once. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is each word on a single line?

Comment: Yes. each word is on a single line.

Comment: Should the result of "Word1\nWord2" be "Word1Word2" or "Word1Word2\nWord2Word1"? Also how big is the original file e.g. How many words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Iterators Instead of Nested Loops

In general, explicit looping in Ruby is not idiomatic, although there are always exceptions. You'll often find it easier to perform what you want using an object's native iterators.

Given a file like *word_list.txt* with a small set of contents like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

you can use [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) to make your pairwise combinations. For example, with Ruby 3.0.0:

```rb
words      = File.readlines('word_list.txt').map &:chomp
word_pairs = words.combination 2

File.open('new_list.txt', 'w') do |file|
  word_pairs.map { file.puts "#{_1}\t#{_2}" }
end
```

You can then verify the results of your output in the shell:

```sh
$ cat new_list.txt 
a   b
a   c
a   d
a   e
a   f
a   g
b   c
b   d
b   e
b   f
b   g
c   d
c   e
c   f
c   g
d   e
d   f
d   g
e   f
e   g
f   g
```

Comment: `readlines` can chomp e.g. `readlines('word_list.txt', chomp: true)`. That being said `foreach('word_list.txt', chomp: true)` seems more efficient since it is an Enumerator rather than allocating the entire file to an Array but you would have to replace `combination` with a different implementation.

Comment: What does "#{_1}\t#{_2}" mean I tried running the code but Ruby recognizes it as a variable? Is this supposed to combine the 2 words of each combination?

Comment: figured out that I needed to define _1 and _2 in map

Comment: @SebastianPerez-Delgado `_1` and `_2` are positional parameters in Ruby 3.0.0. You can replace them with named variables if you prefer.